# Angular4 material datepicker timezone issue after JSON.stringify

Tags: angular, datepicker, angular-material, momentjs

I am facing a problem in my angulr4 application with timezone value. The problem is as follows. When I select a date from mat-datepicker, the value is as follows
`Fri Oct 10 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0530`  but after submission, its value changes to `2018-10-09T18:30:00.000Z`  , The problem Is the actual data from form is converted using JSON.stingify which changes the timezone to utc. I have founded a solition where adding time to current selected date (ie the difference between my time and utc time) Is there any way to set time on datepicker date seletion .

Ie when i select date from date picker `Fri Oct 10 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0530`   Is it possible to set a time, I need it in a common place because my form has several datepickers

Comment: try this.. `date.setMinutes((date.getTimezoneOffset() * -1));`

Comment: Where I can set this in angular mat-datepicker? ie on date selection, I need it in a common place.. no need of repeatcode fpr each datepicker

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35731527/6251232